# Can't crosscompile Qt5.11.1 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: qt, qt5, cross-platform, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I can't get Qt5.11.1 cross compile... 
I've tried different solutions like:

- https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204529
- https://wiki.qt.io/index.php?title=Raspberrypi_beginners_guide&redirect=no

My OS is manjaro and raspberry one is raspbian.

this is my configure command:

```
./Src/configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /run/media/luca/rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -skip qtwebengine -skip qtscript -nomake examples -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -v -no-use-gold-linker -nomake tests -no-compile-examples -no-pch -eglfs -skip qtwaylan
```

and this is the output:

```
    make[3]: ingresso nella directory "/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/QtPi3Bplus_build/qtbase/src/network"
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/run/media/luca/rootfs -DOPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10100000L -O2 -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_USE_SYSTEM_PROXIES -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_BUILD_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network -I. -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network/kernel -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I../../include -I../../include/QtNetwork -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.11.1 -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.11.1/QtNetwork -I../../include/QtNetwork/5.11.1 -I../../include/QtNetwork/5.11.1/QtNetwork -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.11.1 -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.11.1/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore/5.11.1 -I../../include/QtCore/5.11.1/QtCore -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore -I.moc -I/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -o .obj/qsslsocket_openssl11.o /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl11.cpp
In file included from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1:0,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/../../src/network/kernel/qtnetworkglobal.h:43,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/qtnetworkglobal.h:1,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.11.1/QtNetwork/private/../../../../../src/network/kernel/qtnetworkglobal_p.h:54,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtNetwork/5.11.1/QtNetwork/private/qtnetworkglobal_p.h:1,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qssl_p.h:56,
                 from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl11.cpp:59:
/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:121:49: error: static assertion failed: Required feature library for file /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary.h not available.
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                 ^
/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h:87:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X’
 #define QT_REQUIRE_CONFIG(feature) Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QT_FEATURE_##feature == 1, "Required feature " #feature " for file " __FILE__ " not available.")
                                    ^
/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary.h:45:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘QT_REQUIRE_CONFIG’
 QT_REQUIRE_CONFIG(library);
 ^
make[3]: *** [Makefile:27760: .obj/qsslsocket_openssl11.o] Error 1
make[3]: uscita dalla directory "/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/QtPi3Bplus_build/qtbase/src/network"
make[2]: *** [Makefile:275: sub-network-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/QtPi3Bplus_build/qtbase/src"
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/QtPi3Bplus_build/qtbase"
```

someone know the problem??

Comment: @eyllanesc: thanks for corrections

Answer (score 0):

`from /home/luca/Dev/Qt/5.11.1/Src/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl11.cpp:59:`

It would seem you are missing openSSL libraries. Configure with **-no-openssl** if you can live without openSSL, or try to install it into your sysroot and try with **-openssl-runtime** .

Comment: I have it installed both 1.1 and 1.0, I have the dev versions. I will try this option. Instead which modules depend on openssl. I theory I just need the widgets and I don't use any server/client functionality or internet acess.

Comment: tried... -openssl-runtime doesn't work, -no-openssl work but then it stop somewhere else... for missing other stuff. Conclusion building Qt is a s***t (had other terrible experience in other OS).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And the problem was that *Qt* couldn't find *libdl.so* To fix this I put *libdl.so* in */sysroot/usr/lib*.

To find it i add *-feature-library* flag to *./configure*. That command what i use:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/second/proj/dai/env/work/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /mnt/second/proj/dai/env/work/qt5pi -hostprefix /mnt/second/proj/dai/env/work/qt5 -v -no-use-gold-linker -sql-mysql -mysql_config /mnt/second/proj/dai/env/work/../mysql_config -ssl -openssl-runtime -feature-library
```

Comment: I don't think I will try it, I used python in the end... It's much quicker to get the project to work on Raspberry... Qt need too much effort to be compiled in my opinion